# Is there a way to reload ViewSet on each GET request for new data in DRF?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to generate a random object from my Model. The problem is that it will only work one time, then I have to restart the server to get a new object. It just keeps giving me the same object until the restart.

I have been looking for solution on stack overflow but haven't found any.

Views.py

```py
def dailyaskist(category):
    qs = Task.objects.filter(category=category)
    max_num = len(qs)
    while True:
        pk = random.randint(1, max_num)
        task = Task.objects.filter(pk=pk).first()
        if task:
            return task.pk


class DailyTaskEcommerceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    category = 'ecommerce'
    task_pk = dailyaskist(category)
    queryset = Task.objects.filter(pk=task_pk)
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
```

serialisers.py

```py
class StepSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    task_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Task.objects.all(), source='task.id')

    class Meta:
        model = Step
        fields = ('title', 'description', 'done', 'task_id')


class TaskSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    steps = StepSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('title', 'description', 'video', 'done', 'steps')
```

models.py

```py
Categories = (
    ('ecommerce', 'Ecommerce'),
)


class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=360)
    video = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    category = models.CharField(choices=Categories, default='', max_length=30)
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Step(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name='steps', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=360)
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I want to receive a new object (task) each time I make a GET request using the DailyTaskEcommerceViewSet.

Thanks in advance! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this in a method. In this case, `get_queryset` seems the right place.

```
class DailyTaskEcommerceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
    category = 'ecommerce'

    def get_queryset(self):
        task_pk = dailyaskist(self.category)
        return Task.objects.filter(pk=task_pk)
```

Comment: Thank you! I almost got it right. I get """basename argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a queryset"""

Comment: So as the error says, you need to specify the basename in the router: `router.register(r'whatever', UserViewSet, basename='tasks')`